# Android send sms without notification

Tags: java, android, kotlin, authentication, smsmanager

I need to send sms to my number without notification using SmsManager for the authentication purpose. Please suggest me how to solve this.

I'm using broadcast receiver to read the SMS, so need to send the SMS in silent mode

Using the below logic to send SMS

`SmsManager.getSmsManagerForSubscriptionId(subscriptionId).sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, randomNumber, null, null);`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.